# Question involving proof by contrapositive of: If $n$ is even, then $nk$ is even, where $k \in \mathbb Z$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

The contrapositive of the statement is: If $nk$ is odd, then $n$ is odd; where $k \in \mathbb Z$.

I am using the cases where $k$ is odd and $k$ is even.

If $k$ is odd:
$$nk=2l+1$$
$$n(2m+1)=2l+1$$
$$2mn+n=2l+1$$
$$2mn-2l-1=-n$$
$$2(mn-l)-1=-n$$
$$2(l-mn)+1=n$$

So, $n$ is odd.

Now, if $k$ is even, then

$$nk=2l+1$$
$$n(2m)=2l+1$$
$$2(mn)=2l+1$$

So, we have even is equal to odd. So, $k$ cannot be even.

**Does that change the domain in the contrapositive, hence making the two statements not equal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we make the claim 'if n is even, then nk is even', we are *not* restricting the domain to where $n$ is even: the claim as a *whole* is about the *whole* domain. As another example: If I say 'All even integers greater than 2 are the sum of two prime numbers', I am making that claim within the domain of *all* numbers ... I am just claiming that *some* of the numbers from that domain have some interesting property.

So in your case, once we specify that $n$ and $k$ are integers, we have fixed our domain, and that is not going to change. Even if the 'if' part of a conditional claim like *seems* to restrict the domain .. it does not. Likewise, the contrapositive 'if nk is odd, then n is even' *still* assumes that the domain for $n$ and $k$ is *all* integers.

And otherwise, this is indeed a perfectly good proof by contraposition ... Maybe clean it up a little bit by *first* showing that $k$ cannot be even, and then showing that $n$ has to be odd (all under the assumption that $nk$ is odd, of course). But again, none of that changes the domain that the claims were about.

Comment: Thanks. But if $k$ is not even then doesn't that mean the original statement is limited?

Comment: @AlJebr Oh, now I see what you were asking!  OK, I'll add that to my answer.